# Java Swing BufferedImage poor quality

Tags: java, swing, bufferedimage

I'm trying to create a drawing on BufferedImage and then copy in onto JPanel.
When I draw directly on JPanel quality of the picture is v.good but when using intermediate BufferedImage quality / resolution is visibly reduced.
I've checked that with zoom option from OSX's Accessibility panel.
I'm developing on MacBook Pro Retina.

Is there some sort of automated scaling happening?
What am I doing wrong with BufferedImage?

Here's the code demonstrating the problem

```
package com.sample.gui;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class QualityProblem {

private static final double DOT_SIZE = 4;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("ChartPanel demo");
    frame.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    // JPanel draw = new DrawingOK();
    JPanel draw = new DrawingUgly();
    draw.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    frame.getContentPane().add(draw, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(1200, 900));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.setVisible(true);
}

private static class DrawingOK extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2draw = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        try {
            g2draw.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2draw.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
            g2draw.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);

            Ellipse2D.Double e = new Ellipse2D.Double(50, 50, DOT_SIZE, DOT_SIZE);
            g2draw.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            g2draw.fill(e);
        } finally {
            g2draw.dispose();
        }
    }
}

private static class DrawingUgly extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Dimension size = getParent().getSize();
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(size.width, size.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

        Graphics2D ig = image.createGraphics();
        ig.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        ig.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
        ig.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);

        Graphics2D g2draw = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        try {
            Ellipse2D.Double e = new Ellipse2D.Double(50, 50, DOT_SIZE, DOT_SIZE);
            ig.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            ig.fill(e);
            g2draw.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        } finally {
            ig.dispose();
            g2draw.dispose();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Edited:
Added images with 4 pixel dot and 50D both zoomed in.
Ugly one comes from BufferedImage copied onto screen's Graphics
[image: Small 4pixel dot]
[image: Big balls]

Comment: Looks identical for me. Can you post screenshots (maybe zoomed in)?

Comment: It is likely that the `Graphics` object obtained from the image is using different **rendering hints** than are used in the panel.

Comment: Try creating the `BufferedImage` with twice the size (ie. `size.width * 2, size.height * 2`), then set `ig`'s scale to `2` and `g2draw`'s scale to `0.5`.

Comment: Thanks haraldK! That was it! I tried something similar but in a desperate attempt to find solution I was clearly doing something wrong. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

I fixed up your drawing code.

Here's the ugly GUI.

[image: ChartPanel demo]

1. I moved the sizing of the panel to the panel constructor.  Setting the frame size includes the borders.  Setting the panel size gives you the drawing area you want.
2. I moved the black background painting to the paintComponent method.  You might as well do all the painting in one place.
3. I cleaned up your drawing code.  You don't need to make a copy of the paintComponent graphics instance to get Graphics2D.
4. I made the circle bigger so you could see the sharpness.  I moved the origin to the center of the circle, and turned the DOT_SIZE into a radius.

Here's the code.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class QualityProblem implements Runnable {

    private static final double DOT_SIZE = 50D;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new QualityProblem());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("ChartPanel demo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        // JPanel draw = new DrawingOK();
        JPanel draw = new DrawingUgly();

        frame.getContentPane().add(draw, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private class DrawingOK extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public DrawingOK() {
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 400));
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            Graphics2D g2draw = (Graphics2D) g;

            g2draw.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2draw.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
            g2draw.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);

            g2draw.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2draw.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

            Ellipse2D.Double e = new Ellipse2D.Double(300D - DOT_SIZE,
                    200D - DOT_SIZE, DOT_SIZE + DOT_SIZE, DOT_SIZE + DOT_SIZE);
            g2draw.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            g2draw.fill(e);
        }
    }

    private class DrawingUgly extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public DrawingUgly() {
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 400));
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(getWidth(), getHeight(),
                    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

            Graphics2D ig = image.createGraphics();
            ig.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            ig.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
            ig.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);

            ig.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            ig.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

            Ellipse2D.Double e = new Ellipse2D.Double(300D - DOT_SIZE,
                    200D - DOT_SIZE, DOT_SIZE + DOT_SIZE, DOT_SIZE + DOT_SIZE);
            ig.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            ig.fill(e);
            ig.dispose();

            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Gilbert, thanks for answer but your changes are pure cosmetics and don't solve my problem with uneven edges when zoomed in. See pictures

Answer (score 1):

This is simply because in one case, you're drawing on a hardware-supported surface that *says* it's 640x480 but rendering is done at 2x (or whatever scaling factor of your display) resolution. In the case of `BufferedImage` you're drawing onto a literal 640x480 pixel buffer. Obviously, that will look worse.

Comment: It must be something related to Retina display how it renders.
I found more information here https://bulenkov.com/2013/06/23/retina-support-in-oracle-jdk-1-7/

Answer (score 1):

I think that the image and panel are using different rendering hints on OS X for hints you've not explicitly set.  Copy/paste the textual output of this code back into the question.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class QualityProblem {

    private static final double DOT_SIZE = 40;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("ChartPanel demo");
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));

        frame.getContentPane().add(new DrawingUgly());
        frame.getContentPane().add(new DrawingOK());
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static class DrawingOK extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        DrawingOK() {
            setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            Graphics2D g2draw = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            System.out.println("Panel Rendering Hints:");
            printRenderingHints(g2draw);
            try {
                g2draw.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                g2draw.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
                g2draw.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);

                Ellipse2D.Double e = new Ellipse2D.Double(50, 50, DOT_SIZE, DOT_SIZE);
                g2draw.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                g2draw.fill(e);
            } finally {
                g2draw.dispose();
            }
        }
    }

    private static class DrawingUgly extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        DrawingUgly() {
            setBackground(Color.RED);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            Dimension size = getParent().getSize();
            BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(size.width, size.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

            Graphics2D ig = image.createGraphics();

            System.out.println("Image Rendering Hints:");
            printRenderingHints(ig);
            ig.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            ig.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
            ig.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);

            Graphics2D g2draw = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            try {
                Ellipse2D.Double e = new Ellipse2D.Double(50, 50, DOT_SIZE, DOT_SIZE);
                ig.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                ig.fill(e);
                g2draw.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
            } finally {
                ig.dispose();
                g2draw.dispose();
            }
        }
    }

    private static void printRenderingHints(Graphics2D g) {
        RenderingHints renderingHints = g.getRenderingHints();
        RenderingHints.Key[] renderHintsKeys = {
            RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION,
            RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING,
            RenderingHints.KEY_DITHERING,
            RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS,
            RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
            RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,
            RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL,
            RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_LCD_CONTRAST
        };
        for (RenderingHints.Key key : renderHintsKeys) {
            Object o = renderingHints.get(key);
            String value = o==null ? "null" : o.toString();
            System.out.println(key + " \t" + value);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that on **Windows** it produces an identical list of values.

Comment: Hi Andrew It's one of the first things I've checked. On my Macbook Retina your code prints the same values as well. It's more likely to be related to higher resolution on Retina display.

Comment: *"..code prints: .."*  ..what?  Edit the output into the question.

Comment: I could not paste, too much text    `Panel Rendering Hints:  
Alpha blending interpolation method key  null
Global antialiasing enable key  Nonantialiased rendering mode
Color rendering quality key  null
Dithering quality key  null
Fractional metrics enable key  Integer text metrics mode
Image interpolation method key  null
Global rendering quality key  Default rendering methods
Stroke normalization control key  Default stroke normalization
Text-specific antialiasing enable key  Default antialiasing text mode
Text-specific LCD contrast key  140
Image Rendering Hints:  `   exactly the same

Comment: @ivenhov: For better readability, edit _your question_ to include these results.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Same on Mac OS X 10.9 & 10.10, both _sans_ retina display. @

Comment: @ivenhov: Does changing the interpolation hint help?

Answer (score 1):

HaraldK in one comments below question gave really good advice. BufferedImage size needs to be multiplied by 2, Graphics2D for that image must be set with scale 2 and target Graphics2D (of the screen device) needs to be scaled with 0.5.
With those settings both circles look exactly the same when zoomed in.
Bellow complete, modified DrawingUgly class.

```
    private static class DrawingUgly extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public DrawingUgly() {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 25));
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2draw = (Graphics2D) g.create();

        double scale = 2;
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage((int) (getWidth() * scale), (int) (getHeight() * scale), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

        Graphics2D ig = image.createGraphics();
        ig.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        ig.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
        ig.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);

        ig.scale(scale, scale);

        ig.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        ig.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        Ellipse2D.Double e = new Ellipse2D.Double(10, 10, DOT_SIZE, DOT_SIZE);
        ig.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        ig.fill(e);
        ig.dispose();

        g2draw.scale(1.0d / scale, 1.0d / scale);

        g2draw.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't reliably assume the scaling factor is two.

Comment: No. But you can fetch it via reflection `GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    final GraphicsDevice device = env.getDefaultScreenDevice();
      Field field = device.getClass().getDeclaredField("scale");`

Comment: That doesn't look particularly portable either. And I think even with that, text doesn't render well. The unfortunate answer is, there is no good way to do this until Java gets an HDPI api